# Adding separator to alphanumeric string using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as : A123456789BC

And I would like the output to be : A-123-456-789-BC for display purposes.

I am using a regex in replace function but so far it only does : A-123-456-789BC

This is what I have -

`String.replace(/(\d{3})/g, (found) => {return '-' + found});`

Basically if I have an alphanumeric string as above, I would like the numbers to be grouped in 3 and add separators(-) to their start and end.

Would appreciate any help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a match for the ending and you should have it. So match 3 numbers or two characters at the end.

```js
console.log('A123456789BC'.replace(/(\d{3}|[A-Z]+$)/g, '-$1'))
```

Comment: So why the downvote for the regular expression? Just trying to figure out why someone had issue with it since I am not sure what the problem would be. Yes there can be more complicated ones, but for this, I do not think it needed to be overly complicated.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. This resolved my issue.
Wanted to ask - I get the string as part of a response. So it can vary. So today the string is of 12 characters long. Tomorrow it might be 13 characters long. In such a case this groups the last 4 digits as one. 
So can this regex still treat varying lengths of string as one - like instead of treating the last 4 digits as one(-2341-) it groups as -234-1-.

Comment: So you would change the numbers to match 1 to 3 `\d{1,3}`

Answer (score 0):

I would update your regular expression like this:

```
String.replace(/(\d{3}|(?<=\d{3})\D)/g, (found) => {return '-' + found})
```

This will not only add a hyphen before a group of 3 digits, but also before a non-digit character following a group of 3 digits.

```js
console.log('A123456789BC'.replace(/(\d{3}|(?<=\d{3})\D)/g, (found) => {return '-' + found}))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out. But my ts file threw an error - Invalid regular expression: /(\d{3}|(?<=\d{3})\D)/ : Invalid group